# PowerShell Copy and Rename Files in the same Folder

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of file which I like to `copy` or `duplicate` in the same `folder` but renaming part of the `filename` during the copying...

Ex.
Copying these files

```
¸Ó¸®30_³²_0.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_1.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_2.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_3.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_10.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_11.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_12.pal
```

But must be renamed to these

```
¸Ó¸®31_³²_0.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_1.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_2.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_3.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_10.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_11.pal
¸Ó¸®31_³²_12.pal
```

Also I want an `input` of what to `copy` and what it will be renamed to...
I only need to `input` **30_** for the `files` to `copy` then `input` **31_** or **41_** for the `copied` `files`..

If it's not possible for `input`.. I can do with hard coded value...

**Update:**

I found a code that copies and renames the files..

```
Get-ChildItem '*30_*.pal' -recurs | % {
   $copyto = $_.FullName -replace "30_","41_"
   Copy-Item $_.FullName $copyto
}
```

The `input` is what's missing now.. and I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Have you attempted writing any code to satisfy these requirements?

Comment: No.. I am not very familiar with PowerShell.. but I found some sources.. but its only for copying files to another folder...

Comment: You have to show your effort first. Showing your requirement wont be helped in SO. Go through [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RanadipDutta I have been searching and testing while waiting some help from here.. I am making efforts in my own end... I just don't know PowerShell commands.. the Code above are the result of many searches and testing in my own end... and finally found a code that works for me...

Answer (score 0):

This should replace the each file if your get-childitem is working properly

```
Get-ChildItem '*30_*.pal' -Recurse |% {$_.Replace('30','31')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranadip Dutta's answer is good, but the replace might give issues if the second set of numbers ever contains a 30...for example, if there are more files in the group and you have one:

```
¸Ó¸®30_³²_30.pal
```

It would get renamed to:

```
¸Ó¸®31_³²_31.pal
```

In order to avoid this, use more identifying characters in the Replace to be sure that you are replacing the number in the correct location in the file, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem '*30_*.pal' -Recurse |% {$_.Replace('®30','®31')}
```

Comment: my code above work just fine.. but thanks for helping.. :)